# Generating a "similar" certificate

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, pki

== My question probably requires some background:

I am working with a product from Oracle (Oracle Access Manager), trying to configure a test configuration where I have what they call a "webgate", but communicating using "CERT" mode between the webgate and the OAM server.

Enabling the CERT mode normally consists of having a certificate, key, and the root CA certificate and:

On the OAM Server:
- Importing the CA certificate into an Oracle specific JKS keystore
- Importing the certificate and the encrypted key into another Oracle specific JCEKS keystore

On the webgate:
- Put a copy of the certificate file, encrypted key file, and root CA file into a specific directory

From testing, it the same certificate+key (and root CA cert) can be used for both the OAM server side and for the webgate side.

== The problem:

I got the configuration working using a cert+key (+ root CA) that I got from work (with were issued by their CA), but I want to be able to use certs that I generate myself, so I've been trying to create a cert + key using openssl commands, but so far, I have not been successful.  When I do the imports, etc. of the cert/key/root CA cert that I created, I am ending up getting a "decrypt_error":

NioProcessor-1, RECV TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, decrypt_error

I've been refining my openssl.cnf that I use to issue my certs, and I have it to the point that the certs I issue look almost the same as the one from the office, e.g.:

```
> [root@oam ~]# openssl x509 -in /apps/ca2/foo13.crt -text Certificate:
>     Data:
>         Version: 3 (0x2)
>         Serial Number: 15375053440205592664 (0xd55f29a4b21a1858)
>     Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
>         Issuer: C=US, O=My Company, CN=JL-Test-CA
>         Validity
>             Not Before: Jul  5 01:03:02 2016 GMT
>             Not After : Jul  3 01:03:02 2026 GMT
>         Subject: C=US, ST=VA, L=Herndon, O=o, OU=ou, CN=foo13
>         Subject Public Key Info:
>             Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
>                 Public-Key: (2048 bit)
>                 Modulus:
>                     00:e3:71:40:0f:a5:08:72:50:33:67:6e:57:a5:c0:
>                     7d:b5:a7:26:4a:4c:af:ed:59:f1:42:57:a6:0e:a1:
>                     d5:aa:10:40:f5:d9:cf:bb:21:52:59:4b:54:0d:ca:
>                     ef:b6:6a:b7:c4:dd:d6:81:c0:d8:cb:5a:2d:69:ca:
>                     d4:ec:f1:c1:b7:03:32:f9:bd:9c:b8:77:43:1d:c0:
>                     c9:48:be:62:08:f2:57:29:a2:66:98:dd:c6:a2:97:
>                     5c:53:8c:de:78:f1:b2:21:ef:eb:c2:83:9b:94:cb:
>                     a1:c1:df:20:f6:7f:b6:20:41:53:0a:4a:a2:a4:fa:
>                     c7:b7:3c:d9:09:7b:a5:7f:31:00:c9:9d:a4:cf:a1:
>                     87:24:7f:9b:b0:62:0a:8a:ee:90:9c:56:61:e4:9f:
>                     f0:dc:1a:fb:66:34:95:3e:29:3d:50:27:b4:fb:5d:
>                     7f:84:c2:c1:c1:6b:34:8f:cb:c1:de:51:5f:46:89:
>                     74:00:a2:13:60:4a:36:7b:1c:70:90:c5:80:74:0f:
>                     1c:0b:3e:3f:ed:6d:72:d5:4a:e9:2d:e4:88:4a:c7:
>                     c3:ff:d4:fa:8d:00:55:80:a4:51:59:3a:a1:9e:83:
>                     2e:66:13:00:52:fc:aa:80:eb:f5:a0:55:6b:ee:99:
>                     1e:cb:60:a6:e0:b8:21:e3:91:9c:c1:5f:6d:4e:62:
>                     24:a3
>                 Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
>         X509v3 extensions:
>             X509v3 Certificate Policies:
>                 Policy: 2.16.840.1.101.2.1.11.7

>         X509v3 Key Usage: critical
>             Digital Signature, Key Encipherment
>         X509v3 Extended Key Usage:
>             TLS Web Server Authentication, TLS Web Client Authentication
>         X509v3 Subject Key Identifier:
>             F6:3D:09:31:E1:45:B1:96:0C:B8:A0:68:FE:40:1D:07:B6:D0:44:63
>         X509v3 Authority Key Identifier:
>             keyid:F9:56:E1:66:6C:B2:E0:31:F6:FF:E3:98:17:BB:15:88:45:55:4A:B8
> 
> Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
>      45:4e:91:32:44:be:1a:31:62:96:5a:42:61:94:13:6f:3a:ca:
>      44:1b:0c:6a:a2:10:3b:61:44:58:b2:34:b4:41:0d:2a:0c:26:
>      ae:bc:e7:b2:9a:1e:c9:8a:25:5e:f2:55:19:22:06:44:4b:67:
>      83:39:b8:80:2d:b1:9f:06:b7:a7:ec:4c:08:3d:11:ec:c7:32:
>      03:49:70:05:7c:4b:4c:05:30:4d:06:a4:f1:0d:cf:f3:a6:37:
>      4d:d9:31:af:e1:f8:e6:b7:d7:62:7b:06:e0:82:dd:72:2c:1e:
>      92:f8:cd:03:f4:c0:67:cb:0b:ba:af:a6:1c:0b:ff:f2:44:07:
>      83:db:ac:5e:8d:94:fb:51:5c:a7:c3:89:9c:fb:69:c6:4f:49:
>      b7:07:2d:c2:07:9f:46:b2:9a:2c:51:c5:50:c4:57:bf:b1:c7:
>      e0:4b:02:d5:cb:f0:4c:14:a2:cf:73:fc:43:d2:4b:3e:19:0c:
>      25:d0:38:7e:98:f5:db:e6:15:12:bc:d0:3f:9d:93:10:9f:c3:
>      be:29:bd:54:7f:97:ed:80:16:c7:28:1e:39:13:90:a1:15:fd:
>      df:7b:d8:27:52:13:d4:6f:16:90:97:b6:dc:c0:a7:5a:6f:3e:
>      e0:20:88:58:d4:e5:cf:49:bb:1c:00:3a:38:fb:fc:ab:f3:23:
>      fd:89:45:73:9a:65:e9:72:a5:f2:f4:6e:08:a7:06:3e:2d:83:
>      1b:4d:9b:b9:9e:ef:a0:53:7a:3c:de:fb:b3:ee:6c:ab:46:d9:
>      42:f4:ee:0c:0a:88:59:7f:c4:31:33:53:57:a1:26:92:8b:f6:
>      fd:95:82:d5:2a:7d:b8:72:fb:52:a3:35:6d:60:9d:2c:99:41:
>      29:6d:9f:48:91:1c:c1:78:1f:0f:6f:17:c9:42:51:3d:00:cd:
>      f3:9c:69:9a:33:5d:0f:ca:3a:ee:d5:02:ca:e4:4d:d2:35:fc:
>      83:c9:f0:46:b2:a5:14:f8:56:59:c6:43:30:b7:33:40:2c:a3:
>      7e:07:76:d8:55:8d:35:ca:87:db:57:dd:30:25:90:68:84:89:
>      ac:d8:61:a4:58:a5:08:56:64:95:5e:3c:6b:ac:2f:15:8e:02:
>      f2:4d:e8:6b:e1:b3:af:4e:b0:30:97:c5:d1:00:8c:59:6b:f2:
>      c6:9e:cb:3b:ed:a8:c3:af:8d:4f:75:d8:f3:65:5b:38:1e:18:
>      6b:03:ce:31:e3:8a:8a:02:84:3e:c0:e8:bb:ee:b5:4a:9c:f4:
>      51:f6:be:ac:b1:ea:0f:fc:0e:7d:98:78:8f:b5:8e:24:14:32:
>      64:52:bf:6a:94:59:70:e0:75:c8:17:7b:0e:00:5a:3b:a3:63:
>      ff:ab:1a:0c:e1:43:e5:03
```

But, no matter what I've tried, I always get the decrypt_error when I try my issued certs.

So, I've been visually comparing the outputs from "openssl x509", comparing the good cert to my certs, and I've noticed one difference is that the "Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption" in my certs are much larger than the "Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption" in the good/working certificate, e.g.:

> ```
> Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
>      5b:47:09:64:41:d8:11:49:73:a3:ac:47:b2:07:5b:1b:75:a9:
>      19:09:62:94:c6:46:fa:fa:84:b1:22:c6:f8:0b:b9:20:5a:5e:
>      0b:51:df:e2:7a:ea:6f:4a:82:e4:57:f0:c9:69:25:ef:f9:92:
>      17:91:f2:53:d4:08:a0:b6:2f:4b:58:bd:4b:3b:1f:1e:6f:00:
>      fc:e8:35:26:04:b7:03:bc:fa:8d:da:cb:ad:15:d2:7f:7a:d8:
>      xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:
>      51:45:7c:08:cb:45:d5:b9:99:45:c5:14:c8:07:07:2c:c4:9a:
>      de:d2:a3:6e:bd:c8:ec:dc:c3:df:4f:0f:31:02:66:f3:45:e1:
>      92:29:9e:0f:82:65:cf:62:c8:99:ae:73:da:d9:d0:0a:66:f3:
>      4e:7c:60:d9:02:86:d2:1b:8f:de:1d:0b:c0:ef:10:2b:47:58:
>      22:73:2d:19:66:ed:e0:e8:e2:76:32:4a:f1:af:a1:ab:63:ae:
>      c9:7b:94:4f:54:7f:65:b8:ad:82:6b:57:d7:e9:38:2b:78:d7:
>      ac:3f:18:92:7d:42:72:e2:7f:11:f8:67:ab:da:29:ca:8c:ec:
>      c3:f8:94:00:a3:1a:4a:00:6b:e6:82:90:ee:7f:0d:50:a3:c3:
>      0b:ca:34:28
> ```

vs.

```
Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
     45:4e:91:32:44:be:1a:31:62:96:5a:42:61:94:13:6f:3a:ca:
     44:1b:0c:6a:a2:10:3b:61:44:58:b2:34:b4:41:0d:2a:0c:26:
     ae:bc:e7:b2:9a:1e:c9:8a:25:5e:f2:55:19:22:06:44:4b:67:
     83:39:b8:80:2d:b1:9f:06:b7:a7:ec:4c:08:3d:11:ec:c7:32:
     03:49:70:05:7c:4b:4c:05:30:4d:06:a4:f1:0d:cf:f3:a6:37:
     4d:d9:31:af:e1:f8:e6:b7:d7:62:7b:06:e0:82:dd:72:2c:1e:
     92:f8:cd:03:f4:c0:67:cb:0b:ba:af:a6:1c:0b:ff:f2:44:07:
     83:db:ac:5e:8d:94:fb:51:5c:a7:c3:89:9c:fb:69:c6:4f:49:
     b7:07:2d:c2:07:9f:46:b2:9a:2c:51:c5:50:c4:57:bf:b1:c7:
     e0:4b:02:d5:cb:f0:4c:14:a2:cf:73:fc:43:d2:4b:3e:19:0c:
     25:d0:38:7e:98:f5:db:e6:15:12:bc:d0:3f:9d:93:10:9f:c3:
     be:29:bd:54:7f:97:ed:80:16:c7:28:1e:39:13:90:a1:15:fd:
     df:7b:d8:27:52:13:d4:6f:16:90:97:b6:dc:c0:a7:5a:6f:3e:
     e0:20:88:58:d4:e5:cf:49:bb:1c:00:3a:38:fb:fc:ab:f3:23:
     fd:89:45:73:9a:65:e9:72:a5:f2:f4:6e:08:a7:06:3e:2d:83:
     1b:4d:9b:b9:9e:ef:a0:53:7a:3c:de:fb:b3:ee:6c:ab:46:d9:
     42:f4:ee:0c:0a:88:59:7f:c4:31:33:53:57:a1:26:92:8b:f6:
     fd:95:82:d5:2a:7d:b8:72:fb:52:a3:35:6d:60:9d:2c:99:41:
     29:6d:9f:48:91:1c:c1:78:1f:0f:6f:17:c9:42:51:3d:00:cd:
     f3:9c:69:9a:33:5d:0f:ca:3a:ee:d5:02:ca:e4:4d:d2:35:fc:
     83:c9:f0:46:b2:a5:14:f8:56:59:c6:43:30:b7:33:40:2c:a3:
     7e:07:76:d8:55:8d:35:ca:87:db:57:dd:30:25:90:68:84:89:
     ac:d8:61:a4:58:a5:08:56:64:95:5e:3c:6b:ac:2f:15:8e:02:
     f2:4d:e8:6b:e1:b3:af:4e:b0:30:97:c5:d1:00:8c:59:6b:f2:
     c6:9e:cb:3b:ed:a8:c3:af:8d:4f:75:d8:f3:65:5b:38:1e:18:
     6b:03:ce:31:e3:8a:8a:02:84:3e:c0:e8:bb:ee:b5:4a:9c:f4:
     51:f6:be:ac:b1:ea:0f:fc:0e:7d:98:78:8f:b5:8e:24:14:32:
     64:52:bf:6a:94:59:70:e0:75:c8:17:7b:0e:00:5a:3b:a3:63:
     ff:ab:1a:0c:e1:43:e5:03
```

To be clear, I **don't know** if that length difference in the "Signature Algorithm", but it is the only difference I can discern at this point, so I was wondering how I can make a cert that would have similar length as the good cert?  How is that controlled?

Sorry if this is a kind of odd question, but I have been working on this quite a while and am kind of "grasping at straws" :(...

Comment: I *think* that I've determined how to make that "Signature Algorithm" the same size as the "good" cert:  It looks like I had the root CA key created with 4096 bits and if I create a new CA key with 2048 bits then issue a cert from that CA, then the "Signature Algorithm" is the 256 bytes.  Unfortunately is issued a cert from that new CA and re-deployed the new cert in both the OAM server and the webgate and am getting exactly the same "decrypt_error", so I'm kind of stuck again as to why the certs that I am issuing don't work with this OAM configuration?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Comment: The signature algorithm surely not be the problem. Probably is an issue with importing the certificate or CA into keystore. I suggest use the GUI tool portecle to inspect the content of JKS. Ensure also that the certificate is correctly signed by your CA

Comment: pedrofb: Thanks...
[oracle@oam ca2]$ openssl verify -verbose -CAfile rootCA.crt foo13.crt
foo13.crt: OK so I think the certificate chains ok to the CA cert.  FYI, on the server side, the cert+key goes into a JCEKS store named .oamkeystore and I use a Java app that Oracle supplies called importcert.jar to import both the cert and the associated key into the .oamkeystore.  When I list the .oamkeystore (with storetype JCEKS) afterwards, the keypair entry looks ok.  Also BTW that is the same way I imported the "good" cert+key that I got from the office before which DID test ok.

Answer (score 0):

All - I just figured out what the problem was and it wasn't in the issued certs.

Rather, the problem was that the CA cert was a SHA256 cert.

I created a new CA (and CA cert that was a SHA1 cert) and issued a new SHA1 cert and used that new CA cert and issued cert, and I was able to CERT-enable that 10g webgate-to-OAM Server protocol.

Thanks,
Jim